# Facebook Instant Articles Error: Unclaimed Canonical URL

Tags: facebook, facebook-instant-articles

I am trying to understand facebook instant articles. I claimed my url. I can create Development Articles but I can not create Production Articles. This is the error message I get:

> General Errors: Unclaimed Canonical URL: The canonical URL 'https://*****.blogspot.com.tr/2017/04/ghost-in-shell-animeyi-aldk-aksiyon.html' has not been registered with this article. You can claim a URL under Settings > Instant Articles on your Facebook page. Refer to URLs under Publishing Articles in the Instant Articles documentation for more information on how to register a URL for Instant Articles.

```
<meta property="fb:pages" content="***********" />
```

I claimed following urls by adding this(above) code to my blog

```
www.******.blogspot.com.tr
******.blogspot.com.tr
www.******.blogspot.com.tr/
******.blogspot.com.tr/
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: i'm having the same problem. the thing is that it only occurs on 1 of my articles, the rest are ok. Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You claim the URL wrong.

The page source for the canonical source is ".com".

Replace your URL which ended with ".tr" to ".com".

Comment: hi, I need  your help for instant article, can you help me?

Answer (score -1):

URL Feeds Will Be :

```
https://*****.blogspot.com.tr/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss
```